# Angular : How to refresh page automatically and update the data of a component, when DB table gets updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am creating an angular application, with a component C1. The main purpose of the component is to get data from the database table and display the same.

Now if any user updates the DB table content, it needs to be reflected into component C1 immediately without refresh.

I found, we can use setTimeOut() method and call the API again and again with certain intervals and update the component. But, I don't think this is the right way as it is not a best choice.

Is there any feature that angular gives for handling the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use setTimeOut() or the RXJS interval operator then you can create a socket service with socketio or ws.